# How to return from tab page mode to the normal one?

Tags: tabbed-user-interface

Is it possible to close all tab pages and to stay back in "no tab page mode", without exiting?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As [`romainl` points out in the comments](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/42142/how-to-return-from-tab-page-mode-to-the-normal-one#comment75377_42143), there is no such thing as "no tab page mode": if Vim is running you always have at least one tab.

If your tab line is displaying when you only have one tab, you need to change your ['showtabline'](https://vimhelp.org/options.txt.html#%27showtabline%27) option (to its default value):

```
" Only display tab line when there are at least two tab pages:
:set showtabline = 1
```

Answer (score 5):

You can use the `:tabonly` command, to close all other tabpages at once.

Note: technically you will still have a single tabpage open, even if the tablabel does not show up.

Answer (score 1):

I would close all the tab pages (`:tabclose`) but the last one.

Comment: That is the point, I'd like to get rid of tab pages, including the last one ?

Comment: You always have ***at least*** *one* tab page, with *one* window, displaying *one* buffer. That is how Vim is designed and there is no workaround for that.